# ITunes App Screenshot rejected

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot

I have a problem of ITunes App Screenshots rejected. I wrote an app about biography. Example, I will write everything about Tom and Jerry. I would like to use Tom and Jerry picture as screenshot. But Apple's reviewer always rejected my app. They said that i can't use Tom and Jerry picture. Since it's belong to Warner Bros. Do you have any idea about that? Thank you so so much! Please, have a look : http://www.upsieutoc.com/image/DFgo

Comment: in this place any other custom images bro , problem solved

Comment: warner bros has authorized user for this image , are you get the permission for use this in your project that the main reason the app  has rejected

Answer (score 0):

You can't use copyrighted material to promote your app. It's as simple as that.
If you really want to use those pictures, you have to ask for Warner Bros permission and include it as a note for the reviewer when submitting your app.
If you can't get this permission, change your image to a not copyrighted one.